# Different types of connections to FTP through proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, ftp

I'm behind a government proxy, and trying to use the default proxy to connect to a FTP through for example FileZilla (or similar) it gives a 403 Forbidden from the proxy.

However, if I in Google Chrome go to the same FTP, they are able to provide me with a interface to view (browse) the files on the FTP after login. What is the difference in these methods? Can I somehow utilize this to also upload to this FTP?

Chrome does not present any upload functionality, but maybe if another program used the same way of access it would be possible?

As a note, in FileZilla I'm setting a "Generic proxy" while in Chrome it uses the system proxy which currently uses both a script (which I don't think I can use in FileZilla) and a manual proxy, with exceptions for local addresses.

Comment: What URL do you use in Chrome? Is it `ftp://` or `http://` URL?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is ftp://ftp.<mydomain>.com. When you mention it I see that the page I am then shown is listed as "Generated "..." by <proxydomain>.com (squid/3.3.8)". So seemingly asking through Chrome triggers my proxy to generate a page view? While FTP access just forbids it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ugh, I needed to edit that but dont have privieges. To clarify, I am using `ftp://`.